# How to create list with highest values in R with a tiebreaker

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a list in R of baseball players with the most hits in a year for the past 30+ years but I need there to be a tiebreaker in case two players have the same number of hits. I am currently using a formula like

```
mosthits <- merge(aggregate(hits ~ year, data=battingstats, max), battingstats, all.x=T)
```

but this doesn't take ties into account.
How can I create a tiebreaker such as which of the players had the most home runs in that season?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: As noted, it would be good to see a reproducible example and expected output, but I'd refer you to the ```rank()``` function and, in particular, its ```ties.method``` parameter, which you'll want to set to ```"min"``` to account for sports-style ties.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can sort by hits and then by homeruns, and then keep the top row for each year:

```
library(dplyr)
battingstats %>%
  arrange(year, desc(hits), desc(homeruns)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(1)
```